# Multiple spring security configuration not working

Tags: spring, spring-security

In my application i want to have separate spring security implementation based on url patterns.

**Eg. /rest/ ** will have its own authentication provider(basic auth) and**

**/web/ ** will have its own authentication provider(form login).**

please find below configuration i have done

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<!-- config for rest services using basic auth-->

<http pattern="/rest/**">
    <intercept-url pattern="/MyAppRestServices" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <http-basic />
</http>

<!-- AUTHENTICATION MANAGER FOR CUSTOM AUTHENTICATION PROVIDER -->

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<!-- config for web using form login--> 

<http pattern="/web/**">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <form-login/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="nimda" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

In above config first config is working fine ie restservice with basic auth but web with form login config is not working. its not even intercepting the url ?

Please let me know whats wrong with above config ?

Comment: It appears that your second intercept is looking for /web/**/** as your url. Is this intended? If not, you could remove the pattern "/web/**" from html and add it to intercept-url. Unless you're planning on adding more urls to intercept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly refer below working configuration for web authentication::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/images/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />

    <http auto-config="false" authentication-manager-ref="dev" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <form-login
            login-page="/admin/login"
            default-target-url="/admin/workbench"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password"
            authentication-failure-url="/admin/login"
        />
        <logout logout-success-url="/admin/login" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

    <!-- STATIC USER -->
    <authentication-manager id="dev" alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="abc" password="pwd" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```